# Query object with serialized field in OrmLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am storing an instance of this class by OrmLite into an sqlite file:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Address {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String country;
    @DatabaseField
    private String state;
    @DatabaseField
    private String city;
    @DatabaseField
    private String street;
    @DatabaseField
    private String houseNumber;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    private Coordinate coordinate;

    public Address() {

    }
   ...
}
```

And now I want to query the stored object. All fields are set correctly except the coordinate field which is an object of a class that implements serializable.

Here

[Android ORMLite, query by Serializable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967755/android-ormlite-query-by-serializable-object)

I read that serializable objects can be stored in the database by OrmLite but they can not be queried. Is that right? And if that's true, then what sense does it have to store a serializable object/field?

Comment: Do you get any error message or exception?

Comment: No, when querying the address has the following values: ``Address{id=11, address=Address{id=11, country=Germany, state=Lower Saxony, city=, street=null, houseNumber='null, coordinate=[0.0,0.0]'}'}`` So the coordinates are wrong because of having default values. The correct object would be: ``Address{id=11, country=Germany, state=Lower Saxony, city=, street=null, houseNumber='null, coordinate=9.845681190490723,52.6368408203125]'}``

Comment: Your `Coordinate` does implement `Serializable` right?

Comment: Yes, of course it does implement ``Serializable``.